# Is there a limit to the number of homunculi you can have?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

If playing as a wizard with the spells, the right level and the money necessary to create homunculi, is there anything within the rules of d&d 5th edition that places a limit on the number of homunculus companions you may have?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the Monster Manual:

> A master can only have one homonculus at a time (attempts to create another one always fail), and when its master dies, the homonculus also dies.

So yes, there is a limit - you can only ever have a single homonculus.

Comment: "you can only ever a single homonculus" **at a time**.  If you break it you can get another one.